# Add "It's a link-only answer (not spam)" to Late Answer reviews

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, link-only-answers

We have an *"It's a Link-Only Answer (Not Spam)"* option for flagging in Low Quality reviews.

It will be helpful to have the same option (or sub-option) in Late Answer reviews because the closest option (*"It's Not an Answer"*) is not explicit enough about the flagging reason.

Comment: What would it do? Autocomment and then submit a generic NAA flag? Submit a specialised flag? If the latter, I want that flag in my daily toolbox.

Comment: I'm not sure how it should work on the back end for the moderators, but whatever is most useful to treat these types of answers... It's helpful for reviewers because several times my NAA flags got rejected because the moderator didn't see the answer being link-only.

Comment: Autocomment is a must, to let the poster know why their answer is not enough.