# Late Answer and Link Only Answer - how to flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, link-only-answers

This is related to [Add “It's a link-only answer (not spam)” to Late Answer reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251353/add-its-a-link-only-answer-not-spam-to-late-answer-reviews), but there's no guidance provided.

**Note**: I believe this is different from @gnat's cited duplicate. In the cited duplicate, the question is in the context of a "normal" question with the complete complement of close reasons. During a late answer review, we don't have the full compliment of close reasons. Specifically, we're missing the **link-only answer** close reason. You can see it below in the screen capture.

When flagging a late answer that's link-only, I believe we effectively have two choices:

1. ***Its not an answer*** - should be an edit, comment ...
2. ***It is very low quality*** - unlikely to be salvageable ...

Regarding (1), I think it is an answer, but its only worthy of a comment because of the link.

Regarding (2), I think it is both very low quality *and* salvageable if the code from the link is included in the answer.

There could be a third choice: ***moderator attention***. But I have an aversion to using the moderators due to declined flags and the penalties that follow. Plus, moderators seem to be overworked and underpaid, so they probably don't need the additional work.

What flag reason should we use for this type of late answer?

---

There could be a feature request tucked into the question: me (and others) are having trouble with the reduced-set of flag reasons in the late answer review. Perhaps the ***link only answer*** flag needs to be added to the late answer review process. Or perhaps the wording needs to be changed in the existing flag reasons so a link only answer falls into one of the categories.

@gnat provided a link to a similar feature request at [Add “link only answer” to a flag description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261491/add-link-only-answer-to-a-flag-description). In the post, @indivisible made the comment:

> The "First Posts" and "Late Answers" queues could benefit from a
>   similar option. Firsts Posts especially suffer from these types of
>   posts.

---

For completeness, here are all the choices. But I don't believe the other three are appropriate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @gnat - The fellow in the question has the same problem as me (and others): the flag is sometimes declined, and the flagger get penalized. Hence the reason me (and others) don't want to engage the moderators. That leaves two other choices: ***it is not an answer*** or ***it is very low quality***. Which should we use in the case of late answers that are link only? **Note**: because this is a late answer review, we *don't* have the **link only answer** close reason (see the screen capture above).

Comment: I see. You might be interested in this feature request: [Add “link only answer” to a flag description](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261491/839601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aversion to using the *Other...* reason for this is correct - without exception they should be closed as *Not an answer* because they no longer fit the definition of the type of answer we want. If you did flag this as *Other...* then it is quite likely to get declined by a moderator because it doesn't specifically need moderator attention.

If your *Not an answer* flag gets rejected (it doesn't get seen by a ♦ mod directly, it goes to a review queue) then don't worry - it's just a single flag and it's nothing in the grand scheme of things (although it's unlikely to get rejected).

Comment: *"then it is quite likely to get declined by a moderator because it doesn't specifically need moderator attention"* - we agree here. However, the site is *not* giving us the proper flag reason. We don't have the tools we need. Because we don't have what we need and the options don't fit the problem, we are obligated to pass it to a moderator.

Comment: @jww You seem to have missed what I said? *Not an answer* is the correct reason to use: `does not attempt to answer the question`, and `should possibly be ... a comment`. It doesn't specifically mention "link only", but that doesn't mean we need a specific reason for those.

Comment: Got it, thanks. In this case, the site might consider the suggestion of [Add “link only answer” to a flag description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261491/add-link-only-answer-to-a-flag-description). I'm not the only person who has been having trouble with it. There's nothing special about me, so others have had (and will have) the trouble too.

Comment: FWIW _Not an answer_ flag is guaranteed to get seen by a ♦ mod directly if the flagged post is accepted or has positive score, or has been in the review queue before and didn't get deleted. Also, it never hurts to comment flagged post with something like _"recommended reading: **[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773)**"_ to help moderator and reviewers better understand the context of the flag

Comment: Thanks @gnat - I knew I'd dealt with these as a mod but I couldn't remember the exact criteria.